# NTFS Security Settings Authenticated Users not in list

Tags: security, permissions, ntfs

Working on securing permissions on network shares in the office and I wanted to use "Authenticated Users" group instead of one I already had called "public fileshare users". They serve me the same purpose but one I have to maintain and the other I do not. So I decided to switch.

I added authenticated users to the security permission entries list. Set permissions. It showed it in the list with other permission entries. I clicked OK to dismiss the properties dialog box and when I viewed it once again the authenticated users group is not listed.

Is authenticated users one that is only visible from command line or something? I don't have these issues with other AD groups like domain admins, enterprise admins, etc.

Comment: Nope, it should show up like any other group.  Have you disabled permission inheritance for that folder's security?

Comment: it's the share root so all entries are marked <not inherited>

Comment: When running ICACLS from commandline the entry is not visible there either.

Comment: Just to confirm... Are you taking about the security on the share itself or on the folder that's being shared?

Comment: NTFS folder security permissions. The share is configured for both my domain groups to have read/write access. I then control further restrictions using NTFS permissions only.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't figure out why this built-in group was not showing so I reverted to the existing security group I was maintaining.